# DataGrid in ASP .NET conflict of interest with Other postback events

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, datagrid, postback

I have a data grid that is bound to a generic collection. In the Page_Load event, I check for `!this.IsPostback` and call DataBind on the grid accordingly.

Then if I try to implement sorting by specifying the uniquename and sortexpression, it expects me to call DataBind even if the page is a postback.

How is this situation normally tackled? Calling unconditional DataBind in Page_Load does not seem like a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call your databind code at the SortCommand Event:

```
void DataGrid1_SortCommand(Object sender, DataGridSortCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        // Retrieve the data source.
        DataTable dt = YOURDATA;

        // Create a DataView from the DataTable.
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);

        // The DataView provides an easy way to sort. Simply set the
        // Sort property with the name of the field to sort by.
        dv.Sort = e.SortExpression;

        // Rebind the data source and specify that it should be sorted
        // by the field specified in the SortExpression property.
        DataGrid1.DataSource = dv;
        DataGrid1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I am assuming that this should take care of the missed DataBind event in Page_Load due to IsPostBack right?

Comment: Yes, it will take care of your datagrid data databind on sorting.

Answer (score 0):

it is always needed to be rebound if you change the sort as the control will need to be repopulated and not changed. It has been awhile since i have done any asp.net but i'm pretty sure the data is bound on every post back whether you call databind or not and the only reason you don't have to do this manually is because of the viewstate.